# How to predict using a gcforest model when I did not keep the model in memory?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to train a multi-grained cascade forest (originally from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08835v2.pdf), implemented in [this repo](https://github.com/kingfengji/gcforest/tree/v1.0)), and predict just one sample.

Since I get MemoryError when I keep my model in memory, I followed what was written in the demo code and called `gc.set_keep_model_in_mem(False)`. Written in the [docs](https://github.com/kingfengji/gcForest/blob/master/README.md) is

> `set_keep_model_in_mem(False)`. If your RAM is not enough, set this to false. (default is True). IF you set this to False, you would have to use fit_transform(X_train,y_train, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test) to evaluate your model.

However, if I use this, I cannot call `gc.predict([X_test[0]])` anymore and gives the error:

> ValueError: model (li=0, ei=0) not present, maybe you should set keep_model_in_mem to True

Can anyone help me with this? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to try to run the prediction in pc with huge RAM. when running, gcForest would cost huge RAM. Otherwise, reduce the size of trees or nodes in model and this maybe lead to a worse result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean there is no way to predict only one sample if the model is not kept in memory?

Comment: you train this model on your PC, and save it to disk. When loading the model, this error happen, is that so? Otherwise, when does error happen and how you get this model?

Comment: The error happens when I try to predict something. Since I set the keep_model_in_mem to False, the model is not in the memory anymore after training, it seems. I'm not really sure if my understanding of the code is correct.

Comment: Release your RAM, then run the code. If the error happen again, the model is too big for the memory. Then it's better to post your question on this repo. Maybe author would give your a solution.

Comment: remember to give out the detail of your PC and operation system, likes the size of memory. And the dim of features and the N of training data.